# How do I assert that two HashMap with Javabean values are equal?

Tags: java, hashmap, comparison

I have two `HashMap<Integer, Question>` maps that I would like to compare. `Question` in this case is a Javabean I have written.

How do I assert that both `HashMap` are equal? In this scenario, equal means that both `HashMap` contains exactly the same `Question` bean?

If it's at all relevant, I am writing a unit test using JUnit.

Comment: If you are using Java 1.7 or higher version, below code snippet will work.
```Objects.equals(expectedWordMap, actualWordMap)```
.
.
Please find more information here about equals method: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution I eventually ended up using which worked perfectly for unit testing purposes.

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Question> entry : questionMap.entrySet()) {
    assertReflectionEquals(entry.getValue(), expectedQuestionMap.get(entry.getKey()), ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER);
}
```

This involves invoking `assertReflectionEquals()` from the `unitils` package.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 19):

Using Guava you can do:

```
assertTrue(Maps.difference(expected, actual).areEqual());
```

Answer (score 12):

If your Question class implements `equals` then you can just do

```
assertEquals(expectedMap, hashMap);

assertTrue(expectedMap.equals(hashMap));
```

The Map interface specifies that two Maps are equal if they contain equal elements for equal keys.

Comment: The sad thing about the assertEquals function is the error result, if the map were created by different function the key order might be different and finding the difference is annoying. I just created my own diff function that shows only the entry that is different. Too bad the library function Assert.failNotEquals is private, I don't understand why it cannot be public.

Answer (score 3):

Too compare maps ,in your particular case :

1)Check the size of the map if its equal

Then use

```
    `assertTrue(expectedMap.equals(hashMap));`
```

In your Question bean you have to override the  equals and hashcode method.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how HashMap equal method works:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
..........
..........
 Map<K,V> m = (Map<K,V>) o;
..........
    Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
    Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            if (value == null) {
                if (!(m.get(key)==null && m.containsKey(key)))
                    return false;
            } else {
                if (!value.equals(m.get(key)))
                    return false;
            }
...........
...........
 return true;
}
```

Now since, it is invoking the equals method of Value objects, that means Value objects for a given key should be same (as governed by equals method).

Above will help you to understand in what case your JUnit will pass. In your JUnit method you can use:

```
public static void assertEquals(java.lang.Object expected,
                                java.lang.Object actual)
```

See [link](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) for more details.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 1):

I found the **keySet** method of the map class useful

```
        assertEquals(map1.keySet(), map2.keySet());
```

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and better describe your solution, or just post it as a comment to the question/other answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your bean class has a field which will be unique for every object you create then you  should override equals and hashcode method in ur bean class with that field

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compare(-,-)`(Mostly used for `sorting` purpose) of `Comparator` interface to implement custom comparison between objects as your requirement. Or use `equals()` method to compare objects.

Answer (score -1):

```
 assertEquals(expected.toString(), actual.toString());
```

Comment: What if they're different, but their string representations are the same?

Comment: This only works if the values are generic types like integers etc, it does not work with Arrays as values.