# How to mock a method that is expected to return HashMap?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, mockito

I have a method that is expected to return a result of type HashMap, and I need to unit test it.
The method is supposed to receive a string and show the occurrence of each three characters.

```
public HashMap<String,Integer> findOccurences(String myStr){
    return null;
}
```

I need to know how can I write the unit test for it using Mockito.

```
public class TestMySubString {
    @Mock
    private static MySubString mockedMySub;
    private static String str;
    private static HashMap<String,Integer> result;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp(){
        str = "This This"; 
        result.put(" Th", 1);
        result.put("s T",1); 
        result.put("his",2);
        result.put("Thi ",2);
        result.put("is ",1);
        when(mockedMySub.findOccurences(str)).thenReturn(result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindOccurences() {
        HashMap<String,Integer> myResult = mockedMySub.findOccurences(str);
        //assertReflectionEquals(result,myResult);
    }
```

based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627494/how-do-i-assert-that-two-hashmap-with-javabean-values-are-equal) I used assertReflectionEquals but it still returns an error.

Comment: can you post an error?

Comment: Go take another look at the question you linked to.  The comparison isn't between the maps, but a loop checking each entry.

Comment: No.  You shouldn't be mocking the class that you're trying to test.  Mocking is all about removing side effects of classes OTHER than the one that you're testing.  You're doing this all wrong.

Comment: @DavidWallace then how should I test it?

Comment: Try to express in clear terms exactly what the method is supposed to do.  Then compose appropriate input to test that it really does what it's supposed to, and work out what output is expected.  Then write a test that calls the method with the right input and compares the output to what you expected.  But the starting point is always a clear understanding of what the method is intended to do.

Comment: @DavidWallace , thanks, but I am a bit confused. I know that method is supposed to receive a string and find the occurences of charactes with lengths of more than three. So I have chosen This This and found the expected result and I need to compare the expected result with the result of the method. Which part is wrong?

Comment: OK, so why do you feel you have to use Mockito?  I wouldn't, for this kind of test.

Comment: @DavidWallace because the findOccurences does not have implementation yet.

Comment: @Jack Just forget about mocks in this case, just like David Wallace explained. If you mock your unimplemented method, you are just testing your mock, which does absolutely no good for anyone.

Comment: If it doesn't have the implementation yet, then what would you be testing?  Are you trying to do TDD?

Comment: @DavidWallace yes I am learning TDD and in here I am trying to mock a method that is not implemented yet. So when should I use Mockito?

Comment: Don't mock methods before you implement them.  Write tests for them, but when you want to make those tests pass, that's when you should write the actual implementation.  Writing a mock implementation is just a waste of time.  Look, whole books have been written on this.  I suggest you get your hands on one.  I can't really run through how to do TDD in a Stack Overflow answer - there's too much to say.

Comment: @Jack Oh hey, it'd be pretty cool if you could still accept my answer! It's been a while, I don't think you're going to get any other answers. ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to do TDD, you are getting it wrong. You should [^1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development):

1. add a test
2. run all the tests, see if the new one fails
3. write some code
4. run tests
5. refactor
6. repeat

Plain and simple, this is what you want. No mocks or anything:

```
public class MySubStringTest {
private MySubString mySubString = new MySubString();

@Test
public void testFindOccurences() {
    final Map<String,Integer> myResult = mySubString.findOccurences("This This");
    final Map<String, Integer> expected = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
        {
            put("Thi", 2);
            put("his", 2);
            put("is ", 1);
            // etc
        }
    };
    assertEquals(expected, myResult);
}
}
```

After you've got this in place you have completed step 1 of the list that's above. Run it and see it fail (step 2), then write an implementation for your method (step 3), etc.

You should use mocking when your method being tested has external dependencies. For example, you have a method `public String getWeather()` that returns "It's hot!" or "It's cold!", based on a call to an external web API for the weather in some location. Then you'd mock the weather API component to return that it's -12 degrees Centigrade and you assert that the result of your method is "It's cold!". Then in the next test you mock the external API component to return that it's +38 degrees Centigrade and assert that your method returns "It's hot!".